# HTML to PDF using HTML::HTMLDoc

Tags: html, pdf

i have generated PDF file from HTML using `HTML::HTML Doc` but while opening the file, it shows following error what should I do please help me...

**error**:

> Could not open foo.pdf

Comment: Make sure the pdf file is where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what tool you may be using, but you can try using DOMPDF https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

However, I think this is a little old, I havent used it recently, and I think it may be php driven.

EDIT: Its PHP driven from what I read, but is compliant from CSS2.1 towards CSS3 :)